# Rspec undefined method build for #<Array:xxxx>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am getting this error message from Rspec

```
Failure/Error: @address = @owner.addresses.build

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `build' for #<Array:0x007f9faba657f0>
```

Below is snippet from my controller

```
 class AddressesController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @owner   = Owner.find(params[:owner_id])
     @address = @owner.addresses.build
   end
 end
```

Below is snippet from my spec file:

```
describe "GET #new" do 
  let(:owner) { create(:owner) }
  before { xhr :get, :new, owner_id: owner.id }

  it 'response will be success' do
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

Below is my route for `addresses#new`

```
new_owner_address GET    /owners/:owner_id/addresses/new(.:format)      addresses#new
```

`addresses.build` method is working fine in `console` and working fine in my application but it is failing on spec. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Update:

factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :owner do
    name 'foo'
    address 'bar'
    amount 200.00
    country 'foobar'
    state 'qax'
  end
end
```

Model and Associations:

```
 class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
 end

 class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner
 end
```

Comment: I agree with hklement about your problem. For some reason, @owner.addresses is returning an array instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. What does your factory file look like?

Comment: If I were you, I would recommend placing a `byebug` statement in your controller code between the two lines of code in your `new` method and then run your tests. This may provide some more insight but I suspect that something might be wrong with the factory files in your test. Maybe you don't have the associations set up properly in your test file.

Comment: @DanRubio do i need to add address in factory as well? I am going to use pry now and let you know the result.

Comment: @DanRubio I am updated my question with factory.

Comment: @DanRubio In my rails c. owner.addresses.class is `Array` and owner.addresses.build.class return new Address object.

Comment: Ok. We are narrowing down the problem. My guess now is that there is something not right with your associations. Can you post your `app/models/owner.rb` and `app/models/address.rb` file? If I'm right about your associations, you need an `address` factory that has `association :owner, factory: :owner` in it. I won't be able to tell without the model files.

Comment: @DanRubio i have updated question with model relations code.

Comment: Hey @Reboot. I'm not sure what the problem is at this point. I've created a bare minimum rails application where you can compare at https://github.com/drubio1989/stackoverflow I mimicked the code that you placed on your question onto mine but my code seems to be passing without any problem. Take a look around the app. Maybe you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

`@owner.addresses` has to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` in order to respond to `#build`. However, it seems to return an `Array` in your spec. Does your factory override the default association somehow?

Comment: no, even if i remove the factory I am getting same error.